# NuGet automatic versioning with VSTS

Tags: nuget, .net-core, azure-devops

We're searching for a best practise how to use GitHubFlow with NuGet Packages and automatic NuGet package creation on Visual Studio Team Services.

We already use the VSTS "dotnet pack" command with 
[image]

But how to define Major.Minor.Release automatically?
We do not want to use those vars inside the *.csproj or inside the repository because that won't work with Pull Requests.

What is the current best practise here?

Answer (score 7):

You can do this all within a single Pipeline in Azure DevOps (formerly VSTS).  If you are using a git repository, I highly recommend GitVersion to automatically determine the next version number.  You can add this as a build task here:  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gittools.gitversion

In your repository, I suggest you configure GitVersion to run in "Mainline" mode for this repository, this way each time you make a commit, your version will automatically increment +1, e.g. 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3.  You can always tag your commit to a specific revision though.  To setup Mainline mode, simply drop a file in the root directory of your repository "GitVersion.yml", with the contents "mode: Mainline".  This only works on GitVersion v4.0+

Back in the Azure DevOps Pipeline, Run the GitVersion task after your solution build, but before your nuget pack command.  Once the GitVersion task runs, you'll have access to variables it creates that you can use in your nuget pack options.

Under the Nuget "Pack Options", setup Automatic package versioning to "Use an environment variable", then use the variable "GitVersion_NuGetVersion"

GitVersion works very well out of the box, especially for GitFlow and GitHub Flow, but you may want to read the documentation.  http://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Below you will find an example YAML file that does the entire pipeline process.  Most is out-of-the-box except the getting the version number from GitVersion, and configuring the nuget server to push to.

```
pool:
  name: Default
  demands:
  - msbuild
  - visualstudio
  - vstest

steps:
- task: gittools.gitversion.gitversion-task.GitVersion@4
  displayName: GitVersion
  inputs:
    updateAssemblyInfo: true

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.3.0'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(Parameters.solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution **\*.sln'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(Parameters.solution)'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'VsTest - testAssemblies'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\$(BuildConfiguration)\*test*.dll
     !**\obj\**
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet pack'
  inputs:
    command: pack
    versioningScheme: byEnvVar
    versionEnvVar: 'GitVersion_NuGetVersion'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet push'
  inputs:
    command: push
    packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.nupkg'
    nuGetFeedType: external
    publishFeedCredentials: 'Your NuGet Server'
```